# optimizer of a supermodular function

Tags: optimization

Consider the problem 
$$\max_x \{xy+f(x)\},$$
where $x$ and $y$ are in $R^1$. Denote the optimal solution by $x^*(y)$. When multiple solutions exist, we take the smallest one. We are interested in the monotonicity of $x^*(y)$.

Argument 1: since the maximand of the problem is a supermodular function of $x$ and $y$, by the increasing optimal solution property of supermodular functions, we conclude that $x^*(y)$ increases in $y$.

Argument 2: if we take the first order derivative of the maximand (assume differentiability), we get $y+f'(x)$. Thus, necessarily $x^*(y)$ satisfies:
$$f'(x)=-y.$$
When $y$ increases, to ensure that $x^*(y)$ increases in $y$, we need $f'(x)$ to be a decreasing function, i.e., a concave function.

My question is: is the concavity of $f(x)$ needed for the monotonicity of $x^*(y)$? It seems that the first argument does not need it, while the second does. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be any function. Fix $y_1, y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ be any (possibly non-unique) maximizer of $xy_1 + f(x)$ over $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ be any (possibly non-unique) maximizer of $xy_2 + f(x)$ over $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Here we are implicitly assuming the expressions $xy_1 + f(x)$ and $xy_2 + f(x)$ both have finite maximizers over $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

#### Claim:

We always have 
$(x_1-x_2)(y_1-y_2)\geq 0$, and so indeed the nondecreasing property holds: 
$$y_1 < y_2 \implies x_1 \leq x_2$$

#### Proof:

By definition of "maximizer" we have: 
\begin{align}
x_1 y_1 + f(x_1) &\geq  x_2y_1 + f(x_2) \\
x_2y_2 + f(x_2) &\geq x_1y_2 + f(x_1) 
\end{align} 
Summing these inequalities gives
$$ x_1 y_1 + x_2y_2 + f(x_1) + f(x_2) \geq x_2y_1 + x_1y_2 + f(x_1) + f(x_2) $$
Simplifying the above inequality yields $(x_1-x_2)(y_1-y_2)\geq 0$. 
$\Box$

---

In particular, we do not need to define $x^*(y)$ as the *infimum* maximizer of $xy+f(x)$. For each $y\in \mathbb{R}$, we can define $x^*(y)$ as *any* (finite) maximizer of $xy+f(x)$, and still we have 
$$y_1 < y_2 \implies x^*(y_1) \leq x^*(y_2)$$

---

For an example relating to Justin's comment below: Take the differentiable but non-concave function $f(x) = -x^4 + x^2$. Then maximizers of $xy + f(x)$ exist for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, and all maximizers are finite.  Any maximizer $x^*(y)$ indeed satisfies the equation $-4x^3 + 2x=-y$, but there are generally three roots to that equation, not all of which correspond to maximizers. Further, $x^*(y)$ is a discontinuous function of $y$. Note that:

\begin{align}
y=-0.000001 &\implies \arg\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}} [xy + f(x)] = \{-0.70711\}\\
y=0 &\implies \arg\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}} [xy+f(x)]  = \{-0.7071067, 0.7071067\}\\
y = 0.000001&\implies \arg\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}} [xy + f(x)] = \{0.70711\}
\end{align}

Here is a matlab plot of $x^*(y)$: 
[image]

In this example it can be shown that $x^*(y)$ is a strictly increasing function of $y$, and we indeed have $f'(x^*(y))=-y$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$. However, discontinuity of $x^*(y)$ allows $f'(x^*(y))$ to be decreasing in $y$ without requiring $f'(z)$ to be decreasing in $z$.

Comment: This is related to the Lagrange multiplier facts in Exercise VIII-B.5 (page 39) and Theorem III.2 (page 14) in these notes: http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/network-optimization-notes.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much for the neat proof for the nonnecessity of the concavity. Could you please also point out the issues in Argument 2? It also appears sensible, but it leads to a different conclusion.

Comment: @Justin : For your comment, I added an example to my answer (with a matlab plot).  In that example the equation $f'(x) =-y$ can have multiple roots, not all related to maximizers of $xy + f(x)$, and $x^*(y)$ is increasing but jumps discontinuously at $y=0$, which allows $f'(x^*(y))$ to indeed decrease with $y$ without requiring $f'(z)$ to always decrease with $z$.

Comment: Thank you for the nice example. The example also helps me clear some of my original doubts. One of my original doubts was: since the result holds for \emph{any} function $f(x)$, it must hold if $f(x)$ is strictly convex, for which $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing. However, if $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing, then the solution to $f'(x)=-y$ is decreasing with $y$. Then I realized that when $f(x)$ is convex, the optimal solution should not be determined by the first order condition.

Comment: In fact, the first order condition applies only when $f(x)$ is concave in some sense (locally or globally) and when $f(x)$ is concave, the first order condition shows that $x^*(y)$ is increasing, which is consistent with the result.

Comment: If $f$ is strictly convex then $xy + f(x)$ is also strictly convex in $x$ and has no global max over $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (the supremum is approached either as $x\rightarrow-\infty$ or $x\rightarrow \infty$). This is where we needed the implicit assumption of existence of a _finite_ maximizer.

Comment: On the other hand suppose $f$ is _any_ differentiable function and suppose for each $y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have a finite maximizer of $xy+f(x)$ that we shall call $x^*(y)$. Then indeed $f'(x^*(y))=-y$. Since $f'(x^*(y))$ is strictly decreasing in $y$, and since we already know $x^*(y)$ is nondecreasing in $y$, it must be _strictly increasing_ in $y$ (since it certainly cannot be constant over any interval). That is, $f$ differentiable $\implies$ $x^*(y)$ is strictly increasing. This is how to prove the discontinuous $x^*(y)$ in the above figure is in fact strictly increasing.